# Is it customary to build "built-ins" over carpet?

Tags: carpet, custom-cabinetry, built-ins

I am planning on doing built-ins on either side of the utility door in the image below:

[image: Current area]

This is a crude mockup of the cabinets I'm going to build:

[image: Mockup of Cabinets]

**What I'd like to know is whether it's customary to build these cabinets over the carpet?**

*If it's good practice to remove the carpet under cabinets like this, is there any magic to tacking it back down properly?*

Comment: Check your local building codes, in my area you cannot hide a live receptacle or junction box.

Comment: @Handyman:   It normally needs to be "accessible".   Inside a cabinet would count as accessible.   This is a fairly standard way to install an outlet for a built-in microwave, e.g.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should cut away carpet.  The cabinets will last longer than the carpet and will just be a mess when it's time to install new carpet.  I'd want the cabinets secured directly to the floor, not through carpet/pad.

When you pull up the carpet and baseboard, you'll see the tack strip.  If you are careful, you can re-use it, but it is cheap to replace. You'll probably want a tool called a knee kicker carpet stretcher to properly re-attach the carpet to the tack strip.  You can rent them or [cobble one together yourself.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ClB5Zp3QXE8)

Edit:
It looks like you are working on a slab.  In which case you'll need special tack strip with concrete nails and removing the old tack strip will be more of a chore.

In a pinch, or where the carpet is hidden from view, I have used large headed button-head screws.

Comment: If you have a harbor freight or another cheep tool place nearby, consider purchasing a carpet kicker there.  Some of these places are good for purchasing an one off tool that is cheaper than renting.  Just don't expect the tool to last long.

Comment: Thanks @paul these are very helpful hints. Yes, this is in the basement, and there is concrete underneath. :-)

Comment: @AndrewTheken  You are welcome.  you might want to look at what is required as a moisture barrier between the slab and cabinets.

Comment: @Paul - I'll look into that. Those are actually false walls, and the basement has been finished and bone-dry for more than two years.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't call it a "built-in" if built over carpet. What will be supporting the bottom as the carpet compresses?